# Using VAE-GAN architecture on larger images

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm using a VAE-GAN architecture that was originally used on low res images (mnist, faces) to train on audio spectrograms which are much higher res. Does anyone have recommendations for what to change in the architecture to make this work?

A few things I can think of -- increasing kernel size, number of layers/nodes. But it is already quite slow to train.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: while audio spectrogram is 2d... I'm not sure if people uses convolutional neural nets as the first few layers for audios... the kind of layers that comes to mind are recurrent neural nets.. ie LSTM.  A quick google search shows that people do use vae for audio data, search "audio vae".

Comment: this article (VQ-VAE) seems to be related to what you are looking for https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00937